# Dream Train? Looking for a Book

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book about a man on a train.  I read it around 2001.  This man finds himself on a train....but the train is not in the "real" universe.  It travels to all sorts of made up location as if it were in a dream.  There are other passengers on board with him....I think maybe 5?  And each stop the train makes is some sort of group exercise....like a support group type thing but in fantasy-scapes.  I can't remember the purpose of the group counselling sessions, but I remember liking the book and unfortunately I don't remember the title or author.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This might be *The Bridge* by Iain Banks.

From [iain-banks.net](http://www.iain-banks.net/uk/the-bridge/)

> The man who wakes up in the extraordinary world of a bridge has
>   amnesia, and his doctor doesn't seem to want to cure him. Does it
>   matter? Exploring the bridge occupies most of his days. But at night
>   there are his dreams. Dreams in which desperate men drive sealed
>   carriages across barren mountains to a bizarre rendezvous; an
>   illiterate barbarian storms an enchanted tower under a stream of
>   verbal abuse; and broken men walk forever over bridges without end,
>   taunted by visions of a doomed sexuality.

There is a wikipedia page (gives away too much IMO): [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridge_%28novel%29)

The beginning of the book is more about the bridge than a train. The main character has sessions with some sort of psychiatrist. Later on, he goes on a train journey (the train remaining on the bridge which seems to go on forever).